# Can kriging method be used for dataset that is not spatial?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, python, data-imputation, interpolation, kriging

Sorry if the question sounds stupid. I am new to this. Consider the following dataset:

```
|Month | Temperature|
| -------- | -------------- |
Jan | 10
Feb | 12
Mar | ?
Apr | 16
May | ?
Jun | ?
Jul | 22
Aug | ?
Sep | 18
Oct | ?
Nov | 14
Dec | 12
```

Now, can we evaluate "?" for this dataset? I cannot find the documentation for the Kriging method for dataset that is not spatial.

Comment: Well, you have just one coordinate. Your software may or may not perform with just one coordinate, or if you set a second coordinate to some constant. But this is an example of the X-Y problem. If you want to interpolate missing temperatures, you have many options including some flavour of interpolation (e.g. spline) or fitting a model with trend and seasonal components.  It imagine this is from somewhere in the Northern Hemisphere and you should be able to find independent data on seasonal variation. In particular, if August is typically the warmest month, no interpolation method knows that!

Comment: @NickCox thank you for your comment, sir. Is it a good approach to impute missing data using Cubic Spline Hermite Interpolation? How can one analyse for the best method for calculating missing data?

Comment: The only way I know to establish a best method is to test how well methods estimate true values set to missing.